# I want to load Google Drive images from React, but I get a Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) error

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am creating a web service with React.
I want to load images uploaded to Google Drive from a React application.
However, I get a Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) error.
What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert a link in this pattern:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=FILE_ID
```

For example: if you have any particular photo with link sharing turned on for everyone. Just grab the id of the image and use this format to use it as a web resource.

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B9o1MNFt5ld1N3k1cmtVnZxQjg
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a case for me. First, I've tried to use sharing link format https://drive.google.com/file/d/:FILE_ID/view?usp=sharing. It resulted in CORB error.

Comment: Put https:// then try

Comment: Works like a charm with Rect-Native as well....Thanks a ton !!